# Automatically get Visual Studio updates in Windows Update

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ide

Visual Studio notifications keeps showing updates to Visual Studio (e.g. [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt695655.aspx)). Is there a way to get these automatically in Windows Update?

I'm not referring to those of 3rd party extensions etc. Only to those which make sense to have in Windows Update.

Comment: No.  Microsoft is a very large company.  These are very different divisions with dozens of managers in between.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. But I wonder, Office is also separate, and yet we get those in Windows Update. Perhaps those divisions work better together for historical reasons.

Comment: Not how it works, only security fixes for Office are distributed through Windows Update.  Which is the job of the Windows division.  Office always has a lot of them, it is a very attractive malware target.  This question is very pointless, please delete it.